# How to insert a drop down list for year and month into an ajax calendar extender control

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am having an application which should contains a datepicker with drop down list for year and month. So how can I insert Drop down list into an **ajax calendar extender control**. I can't use 3rd party .dll like Calendar extender plus or 3rd party tools like jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think  you can do that with the calendar AJAX extender control. You could roll out your own class extending CalendarExtender, obviously but it depends on how much effort you are willing to put in.

Not sure how strong of a requirement the drop down list is but one thing that I did not notice initially with the control toolkit's date picker is that the popup display shows the month and year, for instance, "March, 2001"  and you can click on "March 2011" and it will show you the months for 2011. if you click on 2011, it will show you series of years; like this

[image]

so it's not very awful if you want to pick a date very distant from today.

The other thing I wanted to point out is that [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is purely a client side script (29KB, Minified and Gzipped) and is not a .dll as mention in your question.